# Game Engine Matrices Multiplication

Tags: c++, xcode, function, matrix, game-engine

I have been following TheChernoProject's tutorials on how to make a game engine, but so far I have been getting an error that I can't seem to figure out how to resolve it. 
[Here is the link to the episode where I am currently at, my problem starts at 28:40.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-minbbZW14&list=PLlrATfBNZ98fqE45g3jZA_hLGUrD4bo6_&index=9)
I keep on getting the error "Control reaches end of non-void function."
I am using Xcode.

This is mat4.cpp

```
#include "mat4.h"

namespace engine { namespace maths {

mat4::mat4() {
    for(int i=0;i<4*4;i++) {
        elements[i] = 0.0f;

    }

}

mat4::mat4(float diagonal) {
    for(int i=0;i<4*4;i++) {
        elements[i] = 0.0f;

        elements[0 + 0 * 4] = diagonal;
        elements[1 + 1 * 4] = diagonal;
        elements[2 + 2 * 4] = diagonal;
        elements[3 + 3 * 4] = diagonal;


    }

}

mat4 mat4::identity() {
    return mat4(1.0f);

}

mat4& mat4::multiply(const mat4& other) {
    for(int y=0;y<4;y++) {
        for(int x=0;x<4;x++) {
            float sum = 0.0f;
            for(int e=0;e<4;e++) {
                sum += elements[x + e * 4] * other.elements[e + y * 4];

            }
            elements[x + y * 4] = sum;

        }

    }

}

} }
```

Here is the the header file mat4.h

```
#pragma once

#include "maths.h"

namespace engine { namespace maths {

struct mat4 {
    float elements[4 * 4];

    mat4();
    mat4(float diagonal);

    static mat4 identity();

    mat4& multiply(const mat4& other);
    friend mat4 operator*(mat4 left, const mat4& right);
    mat4& operator*=(const mat4& other);

    static mat4 orthographic(float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near, float far);
    static mat4 perspective(float fov, float aspectRatio, float near, float far);

    static mat4 translation(const vec3& translation);
    static mat4 rotation(float angle, const vec3& axis);
    static mat4 scale(const vec3& scale);
};

} }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    mat4& mat4::multiply(const mat4& other) {
    for(int y=0;y<4;y++) {
        for(int x=0;x<4;x++) {
            float sum = 0.0f;
            for(int e=0;e<4;e++) {
                sum += elements[x + e * 4] * other.elements[e + y * 4];

            }
            elements[x + y * 4] = sum;

        }

    }

}
```

doesn't return anything but is declared to return `mat4&`

Comment: I am getting an error that states the control reaches end of non-void function, how can I resolve this error?

Comment: Look at the function i extracted from your code. It says it should return a `mat4&`. Either return the object you are multiplying, or change the function to `void mat4::multiply(const mat46 other)`